# SQL query to get immediate parent which satisfies a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a category table where hierarchy is maintained by id, parentid (i.e. one category's ID as parentid of another category then it's a child of that element). I want to recursively go up from a child to immediate parent and check one of the column say FooterAdId is null or not. If null go upwards and continue checking else return the FooterAdId. I'm able to get the top parent with a cte recursive query but confused how I apply the condition to the above described scenario...

[image]

Here I have id 6 in my hand and the result I want as described above will be 101.

Comment: sample input with required output ! would help !

Comment: Please don't make your title all caps.

Comment: @vijaykumar-hadalgi update the question with sample data and the required output.

Answer (score 0):

Use your CTE and include a `ROW_NUMBER()` column there `AS RowNum`. Then, based on the CTE you do

```
WITH MyCte AS
   ...
SELECT TOP 1 footeradid
FROM MyCte
WHERE footeradid IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY RowNum
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Declare @t table (id int,parentid int,footerid int)
insert into @t values(1,null,null),(2,null,100),(3,1,101),(4,3,null),(5,4,null),(6,5,null)

;with CTE as
(
select * from @t where id=6
union all
select a.* from @t a inner join cte b on a.id=b.parentid and b.footerid is  null

)
select * from cte
```